# Confused with php sessions for a user?

Tags: php, forms, session

In my `login.php` I store the username and the user id in sessions. After login the user selects their page and once they are lead to their page, they can select a lecturer name which needs to be only their name, not other's lecturer. I know that this lecturer name that is selected needs to be stored in a session. Afterwards, I have to match either with the user id or username so to control what the user can see. A problem is how to match these sessions from the `login.php` and the `lecturer.php. Should I create a separate file for the sessions?

login.php

```
<?php

 require ('connect.php');

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];


  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

   if ($username && $password) {
       $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password= '".$password."'");
       $rows = mysql_num_rows($check);


    if(mysql_num_rows($check) != 0){

      session_start();
      $run_login =mysql_fetch_array($check);
      $uid = $run_login['id'];
      $_SESSION['uid'] = $_POST['uid'];
      $_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];
      header("location:../../statistics/home.php");

    }
    else{
      die("Could not find the Username or password.");
   }
 }
  else {
     echo "Please fill all the fields.";
 }
}
?>
```

lecturer.php

```
 <?php 

   include 'connect.php';

   $year = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['year']);
   $lecturer = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lecturer']); // Don't forget to handle the SQL Injections ...
   $years     = array(
        2005,
        2006,
        2007
   );
   $lecturers = array(
        'dimopoulos',
        'lagkas',
        'kehagias',
        'chrysochoou'
   );
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        if (in_array($lecturer, $lecturers) && in_array($year, $years)) {

                 $sql = "SELECT unit_name,a1,a2,a3,l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,lavg,r1,r2,u1,u2,u3 FROM $lecturer WHERE year=$year";

            $result = mysql_query($sql);
        }

        else {
            echo "No data found";
        }

  }
  else{
      echo "Please select";
  }

  ?>
 <html>
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../statistics/style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="container">
   <table id="table" width="900" border="1" cellspacing="1">
   <tr>
    <td>Unit Name</td>
    <td>A1 </td>
    <td>A2 </td>
    <td>A3 </td>
    <td>L1 </td>
    <td>L2 </td>
    <td>L3 </td>
    <td>L4 </td>
    <td>L5 </td>
    <td>L6 </td>
    <td>L7 </td>
    <td>LAVG </td>
    <td>R1 </td>
    <td>R2 </td>
    <td>U1 </td>
    <td>U2 </td>
    <td>U3 </td>


   </tr>

   <?php
       while($unit=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['unit_name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['a1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['a2']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['a3']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l2']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l3']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l4']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l5']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l6']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l7']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['lavg']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['r1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['r2']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['u1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['u2']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['u3']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";    
    }
?>
  </table>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>



    lecturerForm.php


    <form name="myform" action="lecturer.php" method="POST" >
<b>Lecturers:<b/>
<select name="lecturer">  
<option value="Choose">Please select..</option>
<?php
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT lec_name FROM lecturer");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

        echo "<option value='".$row['lec_name']."'>".$row['lec_name']."</option>";
    }
    ?> 
</select><br/><br/>

<b>Year:<b/>
<select name="year"> 
<option value="Choose">Please select..</option>
<option value="2005">2005</option> 
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option></select><br/><br/>


<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear">

</form>
```

Comment: Remove `@` from your code. When asking for help the last thing you want to do is hide possible errors.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: removing `@` in this case cause more problems (eg. with `session_start()`), the same problem with undefined variables is in the second file. This code is ready to trash and writing again.

Answer (score 3):

Put `session_start()` to the begin of `lecturer.php page`.

**Note:**
You have bad var name in login.php where set `$_SESSION['uid']`:

```
$uid = $run_login['id'];
$_SESSION['uid'] = $uid; // not $_POST['uid'];
```

Comment: do I remove the '$_POST' from username as well?

Comment: @mapr18: not necessary, `$run_login['username']` and `$_POST['username']` has the same content.

Comment: You remove `@` as comments above said, move `$username = '';` and `$password = '';` in login.php into `if` condition, else the `session_start` won't work. The same in `lecturer.php`, move `$year` and `$lecturer`variable definition into `if` condition below.

Comment: but under which 'if' condition should I move the 'username' and 'passoword'? Under 'if (isset($_POST['submit']))' ?

Comment: @mapr18: sure. If you remove `@` and go to `login.php`, you will see notice regarding undefined variable (`$_POST` doesn't exist). It's an output, session_start returns another `Warning` (`headers already sent`) and the whole script fails. In the second file the same error. Basically, you try to work with `$_POST['username']` before you are sure this variable exists (you know that it exist when `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` is true).

Comment: I put it under ' (isset($_POST['submit']))' and it works fine I changed the variables to the 'lecturer.php', as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76279/discussion-between-mapr18-and-panther).